# Why two characterizations of the arcsine distribution are equiv?

Tags: calculus, probability, trigonometry, probability-distributions

According to Wikipedia the CDF of arcsine dist. is:

$$F(x)=\frac2{\pi}\arcsin(\sqrt{x})=\frac{\arcsin(2x-1)}{\pi}+\frac12$$

So, why are these two equivalent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really about proving a trigonometric identity rather than about probability. (It is of course getting applied to probability, though.)

Comment: I changed "Why two definitions of arcsine dist. are equiv?" to "Why two expressions involving arcsine dist. are equiv?". These are not definitions at all.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, but you can think of these as a definition.

Comment: How would you do that? Suppose you had never heard of the arcsine function and you heard someone mention it. And you ask "What is the arcsine funciton?" And the person tells you $\dfrac 2\pi\arcsin\sqrt x.$ Would you then understand what the arcsine function is? If not, then you are not using that as a _definition_. That is what _definitions_ are for.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It makes sense that someone know the arcsine function but not arcsine distribution. So, I will DEFINE arcsine distribution using arcsine function in it's CDF.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean. I had forgotten there was a probability distribution involved because in a sense there isn't: Answering this question requires no knowledge of probability; it only requires proving a trigonometric identity. $\qquad$

Comment: I've changed the title again in a way that I hope makes it clearer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to prove this trigonometric identity is to $(1)$ first show that the derivatives of the functions on both sides of the equality are the same, and $(2)$ show that the two sides are equal when $x=0.$
\begin{align}
& \frac d {dx}\,\frac 2 \pi \, \arcsin\sqrt x = \frac 2 \pi\cdot\frac 1 {\sqrt{1 - x}} \cdot \frac d {dx} \sqrt x = \frac 2 \pi \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-x}} \cdot \frac 1 {2\sqrt x} = \frac 1 \pi \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{x - x^2}}. \\[12pt]
& \frac d {dx} \, \frac 1 \pi \arcsin(2x-1) = \frac 1 \pi \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{1- (2x-1)^2}} \cdot 2 = \frac 2 \pi \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{4x-4x^2}} = \frac 1 \pi \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{x-x^2}}.
\end{align}
(To make them equal when $x=0,$ one must of course add $\dfrac 1 2$ to the second one; that is omitted above because it's not involved in finding the derivative.)

**A more conventional way (without calculus):**

\begin{align}
\text{Let } u & =\arcsin\sqrt x. \\[10pt]
\text{Then } \sin u & = \sqrt x \\[10pt]
x & = \sin^2 u \\[10pt]
2x-1 & = 2\sin^2 u - 1 \\
& = -\cos(2u) \text{ (This is the double-angle formula for the cosine.)} \\[10pt]
\arcsin(2x-1) & = \arcsin(-\cos(2u)) = - \arcsin(\cos(2u)) \\[10pt]
& = \arccos(\cos(2u)) - \frac \pi 2 = 2u - \frac \pi 2 = (2\arcsin\sqrt x) - \frac \pi 2.
\end{align}

(That $\arccos(\cos(2u)) = 2u$ relies on the fact that $2u$ is between $0$ and $\pi$.)

Comment: +1 by the simplicity and the smart use of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: @Masacroso It's actually no more than the mean value theorem, which is all you need to prove that a function with zero derivative is constant.

Comment: @Ryan ah, right... I dont remembered where comes from. Thank you.

Comment: The mean value theorem implies that if the derivative of a function is everywhere $0,$ then the function is constant, thus: $$ \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} = f'(c) = 0 \text{; therefore } f(a) - f(b)=0 \text{, so } f(a) = f(b). $$ Consequently if $f'=g',$ then $(f-g)'=0$ so $f-g$ is constant, and if $f(0)=g(0),$ then that constant is $0,$ so $f-g=0;$ hence $f$ and $g$ are the same function. That's how the mean value theorem is involved.

Answer (score 4):

Put $x^2$ for $x$ and use $\cos 2x = \cos^2x-\sin^2x =1-2\sin^2x$
and $\arcsin x+\arccos x =\pi/2$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by $\pi$ and take the sine:

$$\sin(2\arcsin\sqrt x)=\sin(\arcsin(2x-1)+\frac\pi2)=\cos(\arcsin(2x-1)).$$

Then

$$2\sqrt x\sqrt{1-x}=\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2},$$ and after squaring,

$$4x-4x^2=4x-4x^2.$$

Comment: Let's see if the equation $0=1$ is correct, using this method... Multiply by $\pi$ and take the sine: $sin(0)=sin(\pi)$? Yes! So $0=1$?

Comment: @Pakk: right, $0=1$ modulo $1$.

Comment: But the question is not if the two expressions were equal modulo $1$, but if they were equal...

Comment: @Pakk: don't worry, they are.

Comment: I know they are... But not from your answer. That is my point: your answer is not complete.